# xml.etree.ElementTree insert into child of child node creating infinity loop Python

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I am attempting to insert an element at a specific child node of a child node in a large XML document (~2000 lines) below is my code:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
class Kapow_commands:
    tree = ET.parse('location/of/xml/file')
    root = tree.getroot()
    seq_id = 39

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def append(self, block):
        node_num=0 
        for node in Kapow_commands.root[13][1]:
            node_num=node_num+1
            if node.get('class') == 'End':
                node.attrib['id'] = str(Kapow_commands.seq_id + 1)
                print(node.attrib)
                print(node_num)
                Kapow_commands.root[13][1].insert(node_num -1, block)


block = ET.Element("test")    

Kapow_commands().append(block)
```

this code scans the XML file at a specific node for class = 'End' then it adds 1 to that elements id and inserts another element before it. However when I run this it seems to create an infinity loop as it doesn't stop inserting elements at this position. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? Or any idea on how to properly insert this element at the desired position?

Comment: I managed to get the code to only insert once with a 'break' at the end, but still why was the infinity loop created in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The fix**

As mentioned in your comment, inserting a `break` statement after inserting the new element resolves the issue of an infinite loop.

**Why does the code produce an infinite loop**

As for why we get an infinite loop, we need to understand what happens when we call a for loop in python. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) we see that a for loop creates an iterator over your iterable object, in this case `Kapow_commands.root[13][1]`, that terminates when we break out of it, when the sequence is empty, or when the iterator raises a StopIteration exception. Effectively, if we expand `for node in Kapow_commands.root[13][1]:` out, we get something along the lines of

```
iterator = iter(Kapow_commands.root[13][1])
while True:
    try:
        node  = iterator.__next__()
        # Body of for loop
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Here's where the magic comes in. Let's call the node with a class of 'End' `End Node`. If our current node is `End Node`, we perform `Kapow_commands.root[13][1].insert(node_num -1, block)`. This inserts `block` into **the current position in our iterable**, which means that the next item in the iterable becomes `End Node` once again. In the next iteration of the for loop, `iterator.__next__()` gives us `End Node` and we're back where we started, producing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

The solution was to put an initialization of the element you wanted to append inside the loop.

So in your case, I would pass a name as an argument and have the code look like this:

```
def append(self, blockName): # here comes the name
    node_num=0 
    for node in Kapow_commands.root[13][1]:
        block = ET.Element(name) # and there goes the init
        node_num=node_num+1
        if node.get('class') == 'End':
            node.attrib['id'] = str(Kapow_commands.seq_id + 1)
            print(node.attrib)
            print(node_num)
            Kapow_commands.root[13][1].insert(node_num -1, block)
```

For my it did the trick. Unfortunately, I don't know the reason behind this magic.